# Windows store apps deploy location

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I created a Windows Store app using Visual Studio(2013). Right-clicked the project and chose "Deploy". Where was the app deployed? What I want to do is to be able to run that app from cmd, not from Visual Studio.

So the question is: where is the app deployed? Can I somehow change that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally installed Windows Store apps are found here: `%programfiles%\WindowsApps\IdentifierForYourApp`. But when you deploy from Visual Studio (for the purposes of debugging and whatnot), Visual Studio just registers the app to run from within your build output folder.

But I don't think you can launch the program from a command line. Even if you try to just double-click the executable, you get an error "This application can only run in the context of an app container"

You can launch the app via the [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx) function in C++ code. There might be another way via managed code, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: If you are right with this, how would one be able to run automatic tests on such applications? It would be a major setback for this kind of applications

Comment: You just have to use the right tools. Here's a Channel9 video about doing automated testing: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-323. I also found this article that shows how you _can_ launch it programmatically (via C++, not command line): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/09/04/automating-the-testing-of-windows-8-apps.aspx

Comment: Those links seem very useful, but one more question: I see in the output of VS this: "Full package name: "tests_1.0.0.0_x86__b6krnev7r9sf8"", but searching for that only results in a .xml file in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository. Also, in the folder you mentioned, nothing seems to resemble my app's name. Any ideas there? I see I have a "tests.exe" in the Debug folder of my project, but I don't think that has anything to do with anything.

Comment: My apologies, I was incorrect in my initial statement. When you just Deploy it from Visual Studio, it is not really deployed to the normal install location (which is what I referenced initially). It is just registered to run directly from your build folder (assuming you're deploying locally). Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/hh771031.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I still hope I will find a way to launch from cmd, but in the meanwhile your answer now fits my question.

Comment: I tried to run the app using the code in that msdn post, but ActivateApplication returns "hrResult = 0x80270254 : This app does not support the contract specified or is not installed.". I guess it's because my app is not installed from the Store, only deployed from VS. So that solution doesn't work...